# MySQL Workbench 8.0 Users and Privileges tab is blank

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to work on an assignment and the professor asked us to create two users to use for the database, however, when I go to the *Users and Privileges* tab and try to add an account, it is all blank. Do you have any ideas?

[image: What I see]

Also when I click the *Add Account* button, it stays blank, and only gives me the options to Revert or Apply.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in *MySQL Work Bench 8.0* and have executed the following script which resolved the same blank issue.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```